# Autcomplete menu not appearing until you type a letter then hit backspace

Tags: jquery

I have a JS fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fRU62/ as you will be able to see from the demo, you have to hit type a letter (any letter but just 1) then hit backspace so there is no letters again before the auto-complete menu will appear. Does anyone know whats up with this? Is it a bug? Is it something I can fix in my code? Thanks.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">4 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>

                <input name="Name" class="items ui-autocomplete-input valid" id="Name" type="text" value="Item Name" autocomplete="off">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="PartNo" class="items" id="PartNo" type="text" value="Part Number">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Description" class="items" id="Description" type="text" value="Description">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="cmd" class="blue-button" id="btnAddItem" type="submit" value="+">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="cmd" class="blue-button" id="btnRemoveItem" type="submit" value="-">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".items").click(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
    var items = [{
        "ID": 1,
            "Name": "HP DL360p",
            "PartNo": " 670638-425",
            "Description": ""
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
            "Name": "Samsung 840 Pro 256GB",
            "PartNo": "",
            "Description": "256GB SSD"
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
            "Name": "HP MSA P2000",
            "PartNo": "AW568A",
            "Description": ""
    }, {
        "ID": 4,
            "Name": "HP BL460c G6",
            "PartNo": null,
            "Description": "HP G6 Blade"
    }];
    $("#Name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: items,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Name").val(ui.item.Name);
            $("#PartNo").val(ui.item.PartNo);
            $("#Description").val(ui.item.Description);
            return false;
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.Name + "<br>" + item.Description + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your source is not defined properly.

since you're not using a simple array of strings, you need to define at least `label` in your objects within the source-array.

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
        "Name": "HP DL360p",
        label: "HP DL360p",
        value: "HP DL360p",
        "PartNo": " 670638-425",
        "Description": ""
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Samsung 840 Pro 256GB",
        label: "Samsung 840 Pro 256GB",
        value: "Samsung 840 Pro 256GB",
        "PartNo": "",
        "Description": "256GB SSD"
    }
]
```

see jquery-ui documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source for more details.

or working fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/fRU62/3/

Comment: ah i see! thanks for that, now the only issue is im using c# and razor to make that list, i dont know how im gonna get label and value into it. i just made it do "label", "value" but that didnt work, im guessing i need it without the quotes? you have any ideas for me? Thanks

Comment: the quotes doesn't matter. i left the quote for better visibility of the difference

Comment: sorry what i meant was that array is made by this var items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Items)); and that can only return "label" or "value" not label value, youre saying that shouldnt matter? Thanks

Comment: fantastic, i needed to change it to lowercase to work! thanks for your help